# Using relative URL in WordPress Widget - what is path relative to?

Tags: wordpress, image, widget

Using WordPress text widget in Multisite, I need to find an image. Cannot hard-wire URL of site because same widget will be used by multiple sites. How do I find the the relative path to my images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where they are located.

if in your theme (or child theme if active):

```
$url=get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/path to your image in theme';
```

or a plugin

```
$url=get_site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/path to your image';
```

etc!